# Traer un menú html

Tags: jquery, html, html5

Buenos días 
Quiero que en mi menu desplegable cuando yo le de click a una opción el me recargue un formulario html sin que se me pierda el menu de la pantalla, había visto que se puede hacer con la función load de jquery pero no me carga ningún formulario,

**¿Tengo algún error en la sintaxis o me falta declarar algo más?**

```
$(function(){
    $("#informacion").click(function(){
        $("#container").load("../gestion_humana/informacion.html");
    });
})
```

Comment: La sintaxis es correcta, otra cosa es que el fichero exista, o que estés bajo un protocolo `http`/`https`, si estás en el protocolo `file://` no funcionará

Comment: El código parece correcto a simple vista, deberias añadir el código relacionado y el mensaje que recibas en la consola de JavaScript

Comment: El protocolo es https tendré algún problema porque sea este protocolo?

Comment: NO, siempre y cuando estés cargando los ficheros desde https también, que es lo que está sucediendo. Tu problema tiene que ser otro. Comparte un ejemplo funcional donde se reproduzca el error. Puedes usar stacksnippets o servicios externos como jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
function carga_item(id_menu){

if(id_menu == 1){

    $("#container").load("../gestion_humana/informacion.html");

}else if(id_menu == 2){

    $("#container").load("../gestion_humana/informacion_dos.html");

}}
```

Y lo llamas asi:

```
<div id="informacion" onclick="carga_item('1')">
  Click here
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```